# I get python frameworks error while reading a csv file, when I try a different easier file it works fine

Tags: python, file, csv, import, frameworks

```
import csv



exampleFile = open('example.csv')
exampleReader = csv.reader(exampleFile)
for row in exampleReader:
       print('Row #' + str(exampleReader.line_num) + ' ' + str(row))



Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/jossan113/Documents/Python II/test.py", line 7, in <module>
        for row in exampleReader:
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
        return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 4627: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Do anyone have any idea why I get this error? I tried an very easy cvs file from the internet and it worked just fine, but when I try the bigger file it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

The file contains unicode characters, which was painful to deal with in old versions of python, since you are using 3.5 try opening the file as utf-8 and see if the issue goes away:

```
exampleFile = open('example.csv', encoding="utf-8")
```

**From the docs:**

Since open() is used to open a CSV file for reading, the file will by default be decoded into unicode using the system default encoding (see locale.getpreferredencoding()). To decode a file using a different encoding, use the encoding argument of open:

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

[csv modeule docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: I get this:               UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 4627: invalid start byte

I could just tell my professor and maybe he can fix it so it can work for everyone, I don't think this is meant to be